# How do I Pass plugin parameters to API code in PHP?

Tags: php, rest, post, parameters, get

I have developed an API that works fine, but only when I plug in the parameters like "Phone" and "Amount". However, my goal is to pass these parameters from a plugin because those parameters will be different for every user. Below is how am trying to pass the parameters $phone_no and $amount, but its seems that am getting nowhere. Could you please tell me how these parameters can be passed successfully.

//Action Hook to trigger API call        add_action('hrw_withdrawal_request_notification','mpesa_request_withdraw');
function mpesa_request_withdraw() {
$user = wp_get_current_user();

// Parameters to pass....

```
$phone_no = !empty($user->ID) ? get_user_meta($user->ID, 'hrw_phone_number', true) : '';    
$amount = isset($_POST['hrw_withdrawal']['amount']) ? 
hrw_sanitize_text_field($_POST['hrw_withdrawal']['amount']) : 0;
```

// API call begins here....

```
$endPoint = 'https://api.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/b2c/v1/paymentrequest';
$B2C_ConsumerKey = "tttttttttttttttttttttttttttytr";
$B2C_ConsumerSecret = "gttttttttt";
$AccessToken = GenerateAccessToken($B2C_ConsumerKey, $B2C_ConsumerSecret);
$BusinessShortCode = 30013;
$PhoneNumber = $phone_no;
//$CallBackURL = "https://payments.dllion.store/B2C/callback.php";
$CallBackURL = "https://letawera.specctance.com/B2C/callback.php";
$TimeoutCallBackURL = "https://payments.dllion.store/B2C/callback.php";
$Amount = $amount;
$B2C_Initiator = "DEALLI";
$initiatorSecurityCredential =
```

Comment: Please specify a language in your tags. Also, please read the tag descriptions. This will help your post get the right views. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.